# How to detect if an image is within proximity of another?

Tags: python

I am working on a top down RPG type game.  This is the method for moving my main character left.  The problem is that ANYTIME I press left, it prints 'trigger dialogue box' and calls the function.  The only time this is supposed to be triggered is when I move my character within proximity of another image (in listofwidgets).  I suspect I have done something incorrect with the 'for i in listofwidgets' line or the math.

```
def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if keycode[1] == 'left':
        self.source = 'characters/walkleft.zip'
        self.x -=6

    for i in listofwidgets:
        if self.x - (i.x+i.width) < 100:  #if distance between character and tree is smaller than 100
            print "trigger dialogue box"
            calldialoguebox() #call function that opens dialogue box and prints message
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: I think your if should be `if abs(self.x - (i.x + i.width)/2.): ...`. This way it will work with being on both sides of the object, and the distance will be measured with respect to the center of the object (assuming `i.x` is the left corner).

Comment: Hi, thank you.  This is probably a much better way to measure the distance, however it does not resolve my problem which is that "trigger dialogue box" prints EVERYTIME I move left.

Comment: Try printing the value of the condition, to seee what's goiing on. I think the issue could be related with the change I proposed, since if `self.x < 100`, then `self.x - whatever` will always be `< 100`, that's why I proposed wrapping it all inside an `abs()`.